# I want to count in if statement in foreach loop laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

As I am new to Laravel so facing this problem and tried it in other ways but it is not working.
Here my blade file

**products.blade.php**

```
@foreach($products as $product)                                     

    <div class="women">
        <h6><a href="route{{'product.single}}">{{$product->title}}</a></h6>

        <span class="size">XL / XXL / S </span>

        <p ><em class="item_price">Rs.{{$product->price}}</em></p>


    </div>


    @if(count($product) ==  3)                                              
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

**Why this is not working**

```
@if(count($product) ==  3)                                              
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
@endif
```

Or how can I count the product in iteration and compare the count number in if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable) like this.

Instead of:

```
@if(count($product) ==  3)                                              
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
@endif
```

you should use:

```
@if($loop->iteration ==  3)                                              
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
@endif
```

But it's quite possible that you might need it after every 3 elements (3, 6, 9 and so on), so maybe better solution would be:

```
@if($loop->iteration % 3 == 0)                                              
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
@endif
```

You example didn't work because $product is just an object so `count($product)` will not have expected value. Also if you used `count($products)` (notice trailing s) it won't work because count of products is the same in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more or less than 3 products, your if statement is never going to show. What you're looking for is the third item in the products array, which you can do like this:

```
@foreach($products as $key => $product)                                    

<div class="women">
    <h6><a href="route{{'product.single}}">{{$product->title}}</a></h6>

    <span class="size">XL / XXL / S </span>

    <p><em class="item_price">Rs.{{$product->price}}</em></p>

</div>


    @if($key == 2)                                              
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't know how new to programming you are, so I don't want to insult you but I've written `if($key ==2)` because you're looping over the array, which is starts at 0. So the first item in an array the key would be 0, second would be 1, third would be 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of the loop, use

```
@foreach ($athletes as $key=>$athlete)

// Some html goes here

{ { ++$key } }

@endforeach
```

add `if` condition to `key`

let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

The array count will always be the same, inside or outside of the loop.

If you want to make a decision based on the current iteration, ex. "on every third product put a clearfix div", then apply the condition to the key if the key is numeric.

Blade provides a `loop` variable with an `iteration` property (starts at 1) to help with this, see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable

Example for every third product:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
...

  @if ($loop->$loop->iteration%3 == 0)
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
  @endif

...
@endforeach
```

Example for the third product only:

```
  @if ($loop->$loop->iteration == 3)
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
  @endif
```